# MSBuild - Console (Exec) pass a large string with new lines as a parameter

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, console-application

How am I able to pass a large text as a parameter to the `Exec Command`.
A parameter which contains new lines (CR/LF).

**Targets file:**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Notes>$(PackageReleaseNotes)</Notes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Exec Command="$(ExeFile) $(Notes)" />
```

**in the CsProj file I have:**

```
<PackageReleaseNotes>
  This is a test asdhasjdh asdkjadhkjasfh asfasfjkasd
  asdaskjhksdf asdjashdka asdkajhasd aaasdas asdkjhjasd asdaf asdasdasd asd,asdad.
  asdasda.asd asdad MHM MHM-MHM
</PackageReleaseNotes>
```

Will get errors like:

```
Error: " exited with code 9009."
```

Guess an answer could be convert/format it in via a function, and then send the formatted text.

*Alternative ways are also welcome the key part to keep is I want to run a console application with a "main method" getting those parameters (don't care whether it be exe or DLL), some guesses could be Box/unbox, other typed parameters if possible, Using DLL/Compile instead of exec with a parameter like that (don't know if possible or not).*

If I change the text to be a single line, can pass it simply, but I want it to be multi-line as it is.

Is there any way to pass such parameter? (like **PackageReleaseNotes**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try escaping it with one of the solutions described here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-msbuild?view=vs-2019

The %3B represents a semicolon char in this case but the double quotes should work too.

```xml
<Compile Include="MyFile.cs%3BMyClass.cs"/>
```

**EDIT**:

This here replaces the **CRLF** characters and inserts the **^** sign which stands for a newline in CMD.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Notes>This is a test asdhasjdh asdkjadhkjasfh asfasfjkasd
      asdaskjhksdf asdjashdka asdkajhasd aaasdas asdkjhjasd asdaf asdasdasd asd,asdad.
      asdasda.asd asdad MHM MHM-MHM</Notes>
    <trimmed>$(Notes.Replace('%0D%0A','^'))</trimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="$(Notes)" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="$(trimmed)" Importance="high"/>
    <Exec Command="cmd.exe $(trimmed)"/>
  </Target>
```

In your CMD you have to revert that operation though...

To me, this seems a bit hacky. Maybe you can pass along a path that points to a file that contains the release notes itself?

Comment: Not sure if that work, can you provide a more complete answer including how I can pass  PackageReleaseNotes? I tried ' ', and &quot;$(PackageReleaseNotes)&quot; and that works if there be no new lines.

Comment: Will do, gimme a bit

Comment: Nice, thank you, will try it, yes this is hacky, for what I want I have a working scenario, was trying to make this as an alternative generic solution for some other needs. +1 and marked as the answer, but at this moment didn't try it yet.